# How to override ToString() in [] array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, overriding

Say, if I need to override `ToString` method in a custom `List`, I'd do this:

```
public class WebUILanguage2 : List<WebUILanguage>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Overridden message";
    }
}
```

but what if I want to override this?

```
public class WebUILanguage2 : WebUILanguage[]
```

Comment: Well, your proposal isn't even valid C#, so asking further questions about such a situation is a waste of time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. You can't derive from array types.

I'd generally advise against overriding `ToString` in `List<T>`, too - usually it's better to use composition than inheritance for things like this, in my experience.

Comment: All I need is a custom `ToString` method. So, no to it either, hah?

Comment: @ahmd0 you can use extension method which takes, for example, `IList<T>` and prints it the way you want.

Comment: @ahmd0: No. You simply can't create your own type which extends an array type. It's not possible in C#.

Comment: @SargeBorsch: You'd need to give it a different name though - just `ToString()` would never be called as an extension method, as extension methods are only consulted if normal member lookup fails.

Comment: As I said below, the reason I'm trying to do this is because this type is used in a PropertyGrid and `ToString` is how it is displayed for a user in a cell. I thought to provide a more readable output.

Comment: @ahmd0: Well you'll need to design it differently, I'm afraid. There may be some attribute you can apply to the property so that `PropertyGrid` displays it differently - but you're simply *not* going to be able to override `ToString`.

Comment: By the way, concrete array types claim to be sealed, for example `typeof(WebUILanguage[]).IsSealed` returns true. But of course there is some magic to a type like `WebUILanguage[]`.

Answer (score -1):

As was said, you can't do that. But as a workaround, you can simply write a new method:

```
using System;
static class Program {
   static string Str(this string[] a) => String.Join(',', a);
   static void Main() {
      string[] a = {"May", "June"};
      Console.WriteLine(a.Str());
   }
}
```

Or function:

```
using System;
class Program {
   static string Str(string[] a) => String.Join(',', a);
   static void Main() {
      string[] a = {"May", "June"};
      Console.WriteLine(Str(a));
   }
}
```

Or a generic function:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
class Program {
   static string Str(IEnumerable<string> a) => String.Join(',', a);
   static void Main() {
      string[] a = {"May", "June"};
      Console.WriteLine(Str(a));
   }
}
```

Comment: For a general case this is correct, but (from the comments) the OP wants a PropertyGrid to automatically pick up the correct representation