# Property MyObject[] display in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid`. The `DataGrid`gets filled with *MyObject* and displays its properties automatically. For most properties this works fine.

As an example, *MyObject* looks like this:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public MainCategory ThisPropertyWorksFine { get; set; }
    public TransactionTag[] ThisPropertyDoesnt { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that `MainCategory` has an override `.ToString()`. It gets displayed properly in the `DataGrid`:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.Name;
}
```

`TransactionTag` also has an override `.ToString()` method but the `DataGrid`only shows it's type:

[image: A DataGrid with two columns where the second column bound to TransactionTag objects displays "TransactionTag[] Array" for each row instead of the names of the objects.]

The data has been added as such:

```
List<Transaction> TransactionList = fillMyList();
this.ImportPreview.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
this.ImportPreview.ItemsSource = TransactionList;
```

How can I make it, so that the `DataGrid` shows the array content, for example separated by `,`?

Comment: The property is an array and if you call ThisPropertyDoesnt.ToString(), you will get the output in your image. It needs to be formatted 

In your RowDataBound event do the following
You an use var listOfStringValues = ThisPropertyDoesnt.Select(t => t.YourProperty);
var commaSeperatedValues = string.Join(",", listOfStringValues);

Comment: Can you please show the code how you _fill_ the `DataGrid` by bindings or code-behind?

Answer (score 1):

The `ThisPropertyDoesnt` property is of type `TransactionTag[]` which is an **array** of `TransactionTag` objects. You overrode the `ToString` method of `TransactionTag`, but not the array type, which you cannot change, see [How to override ToString() in [] array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19746715/6181599) for reference.

You can create a [custom value converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-convert-bound-data?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) that concatenates the result of `ToString()` of a collection of `object`s using a predefined separator. The following converter exposes the separator as a property, which is useful to reuse a single instance with the same separator. You could alternatively pass it in as `parameter`.

```
public class ConcatenateToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public string Separator { get; set; }

   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return !(value is IEnumerable<object> objects) || Separator is null
         ? Binding.DoNothing
         : string.Join(Separator, objects);
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

---

Without auto-generating columns, you would specify the converter in the `Binding` of the column.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Transactions}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Resources>
      <local:ConcatenateToStringConverter x:Key="ConcatenateStringConverter" Separator=", "/>
   </DataGrid.Resources>
   <!-- ...other columns. -->
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Transaction Tags" Binding="{Binding ThisPropertyDoesnt, Converter={StaticResource ConcatenateStringConverter}}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

With auto-generating columns, you would have to add a handler for the [`AutoGeneratingColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event and adapt column generation. You would identify the target column, get its binding and add the converter.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Transactions}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn"/>
```

```
private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object? sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
   if ( /* ...identify the target column here. */)
   {
      var dataGridTextColumn = (DataGridTextColumn)e.Column;
      var binding = (Binding)dataGridTextColumn.Binding;

      // It is favorable to reuse the same converter instance if you can.
      binding.Converter = new ConcatenateToStringConverter { Separator = ", " };
   }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could create a separate model type that implements `IEnumerable<TransactionTag>` and override `ToString` there, but that is up to you and your requirements. For display only purposes, value converters are useful.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make it, so that the DataGrid shows the array content, for example separated by ,?

You could create a custom collection type that overrides `ToString()`:

```
public class FormattableCollection<T> : ReadOnlyCollection<T>
{
    public FormattableCollection(IList<T> list)
        : base(list) { }

    public override string ToString() =>
        string.Join(",", this);
}
```

...and change the type of your property:

```
public FormattableCollection<TransactionTag> BindToThisOne { get; }
...
BindToThisOne = new FormattableCollection<TransactionTag>(ThisPropertyDoesnt);
```