# Is it possible to customize only single member output without rewriting complete record's ToString()?

Tags: c#, record, tostring

I have `record` with **many** members and I want `Console.WriteLine(myRecord);` to output its values. However one of its members is an array and it will be printed as `MyOtherRecordType.Item[]`

Is there a an easy way to customize output of just that single member without rewriting `ToString()` completeley?

Here is a very simple repro ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uUM4u0) if you want):

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new Test("a", "b", "c"));
    }
}

record Test(params string[] strings);
```

The output is:

```
Test { strings = System.String[] }
```

And I want it to be more like

```
Test { strings = {"a", "b", "c"} }
```

or different, the point is to see values. In my case it's actually not a `string[]`, but another `record` type array.

---

I wish there was an attribute, like with json converters, to force `ToString()` to use converter, but I am afraid the answer is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19746728/1997232) and I have to override `ToString()` completely. Maybe I can somehow combine the autogenerated `ToString()` with my code?

I am looking at [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record), but there is nothing inspirational.

Comment: A dump to json instead of ToString wouldn't make the cut, I guess? => https://dotnetfiddle.net/y3LQaB

Comment: @Fildor, that's clever idea, I like it. With prefix `public static string ToJson<T>(this T test) => typeof(T) + JsonSerializer.Serialize(test);` output is very similar and its customizable all the way down with json attributes.

Comment: I have no patent on it ;P Feel free to use and answer what you finally made of it. Glad I could help.

Comment: @Fildor, json is a [somewhat slower](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DLbgTu), so I'll keep the question opened. You can "dump to anwer" for a guaranteed upvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not really a solution, more of a work-around would be to serialize to JSON:

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine((new Test("a", "b", "c")).ToJson());
    }
}

public record Test(params string[] strings);

public static class TestEx
{
    public static string ToJson(this Test test) => JsonSerializer.Serialize(test);
}
```

In Action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/y3LQaB

Output:

```
{"strings":["a","b","c"]}
```

---

Or a little closer to the desired output:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/pzJHhn

```
public static string ToJson<T>(this T test) => typeof(T) + JsonSerializer.Serialize(test);
```

=>

```
Test{"strings":["a","b","c"]}
```